# How to invert preg_match_all php

Tags: php, preg-match-all

How can I invert pre_match_all, so the output of the code below is "you" instead of "hello" and "world"?

```
$text1 = array ('you', 'hello', 'WORLD');
$text2 = "Hello world";

    //preg_match
    foreach ($text1 as $text)  {

    if (preg_match_all("~\b$text\b~i", $text2, $match))  {

        $match = $match[0];


echo "<pre>"; 
print_r($match); 
echo "</pre>"; 

    }    
    }
```

Comment: You know that the solution you accepted is an iterative solution? That means the more words the longer it takes to run. And using regex on iterative solutions is going to take time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php), [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) is enough (it returns `1` if it finds a match, `0` otherwise).
You also don't need the matching substrings, it's enough to know if it found a word in the text or not.

```
$words = array('you', 'hello', 'WORLD');
$text  = "Hello world";

// Filter $words, keep only the items that are not present in $text
$missing = array_filter(
    $words,
    function($w) use ($text) {
        // return TRUE when $w is not in $text
        return preg_match('/\b'.preg_quote($w, '/').'\b/i', $text) == 0;
});

print_r($missing);
```

Answer (score 1):

Split the string by non-word characters and use `array_udiff` with `strcasecmp` as callback:

```
$words = ['you', 'hello', 'WORLD'];
$str = "Hello world toto";

print_r(array_udiff($words, preg_split('~\W+~', $str), 'strcasecmp'));

// Array
// (
//   [0] => you
// )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use str_ireplace which is case insensitive version of str_replace.
If you replace with nothing, what is left is what is not in $text2.

```
$text1 = array ('you', 'hello', 'WORLD');
$text2 = "Hello world";
$text2 = explode(" ", $text2);

echo str_ireplace($text2, "", implode("",$text1));
// you
```

https://3v4l.org/T8o2l

---

Another method would be to use array_diff and preg_grep.
Preg_grep matches with regex the words from text2 in text1 case insensitive and returns what is matching.
Then I use array_diff to see what is different from $text1 and the return from preg_grep.

```
$text1 = array ('you', 'hello', 'WORLD');
$text2 = "Hello world";
$text2 = explode(" ", $text2);

Var_dump(array_diff($text1, preg_grep("/" . Implode("|", $text2) . "/i", $text1)));
```

https://3v4l.org/WOuh6